# Lookup function works, until deployment

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working with Visual Studio Reporting Services 2008, and I've come across an irritating problem. I have a cell in a table that uses a Lookup from one dataset to find the information to display in another. The code is as follows:

```vb
=Lookup(Fields!place_id.Value,
        Fields!id.Value,
        Fields!name.Value,
        "Centres")
```

The `place_id` and `id` are from one dataset (Dataset1) and the other is from the dataset "Centres". This works fine in the preview, but not after deployment. When I try to deploy, I get an error message (where textbox22 is the cell in question):

> The Value expression for the text box ‘Textbox22’ refers to the field ‘name’.  Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope.

Surely, by having "Centres" there in the expression, that *is* the specified scope. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shared information, I can say that your SSRS development version is SSRS2008R2 and your report server version is SSRS2008. Since **Lookup function** is not supported in SSRS2008 and lower version. This is the reason that you are getting this error in deployment whereas preview in working fine.

For any additional information regarding Lookup Function, you can take a look into [Lookup Function](http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2012/10/lookup-function-in-ssrs.html)

Comment: I think you must be right. I don't know what version the server is running, but if I deploy to my local machine, it works fine. Thanks! BTW, is there any good substitute for the Lookup function in SSRS 2008?

Comment: In RS2008, there is not any good substitute for Lookup function. The only way to keep all the required columns in the same dataset.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up using a table join in the dataset query to include the "Centres" set in "Dataset". Problem solved!